# Blender Boolean Not working?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

The difference boolean does nothing on the model

i did check:

- face orientations is correct, all blue
- merged by distance for all meshes
- objects are closed, no holes.[image]

what im trying to do here is cut the 'magma' into this volcano.

[image]

Comment: added the blend file. Decimate it actually and now boolean works but i get a mesh with a hole instead of a closed mesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former *Boolean* bugs as soon as you have overlapping edges, vertices or faces, you need to use the *Exact* option in the new Blender version and it will work fine:

[image]

[image]